# react-facebook-login works on desktop browser but throws "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted" on mobile

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

My web app, [stockbets.io](https://stockbets.io), uses Facebook login for oauth. On a desktop web browser this works fine, and none of my pilot users have had any trouble signing in. When they try the exact same flow on mobile, however, we get this error:

```
URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
```

Here is a snapshot of my settings panel for the Facebook Login service:

[image]

This seems like it should be straightforward, but I'm at a loss as to why this works on desktop but not mobile. The expected behavior, if you'd like to test, is that you should receive a message saying that the product is in early beta but send us an email if you'd like early access. What happens currently is the above error message.

Any tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to GitHub, this seems like something related to the `react-facebook-login` library. According to [a similar thread on GitHub](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login/issues/272#issuecomment-558690559)... looks like you'll just need to make sure the following props are added to you React component.

```
<FacebookLogin
  appId="13xxxxxxxxxxx09"//TODO: Replace yours...
  autoLoad={false}
  fields="first_name, last_name ,email, picture"
  callback={(resp)=>this.responseFacebook(resp)}//TODO: Replace your callback
  cssClass="fbtn"
  disableMobileRedirect={true}
/>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @jmz7z. fwiw, here's my prop pass-in: didn't need to set `autoLoad={false}`.

Comment: ```
                appId={process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_APP_ID}
                disableMobileRedirect={true}
                fields="name,email,picture"
                callback={handleSubmit}
                render={(renderProps) => ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the disableMobileRedirect={true} solved the issue.
I was not understanding the behavior as it was working just fine in Desktop devices but not on mobile. But now it works.